# Trying to structure with call by value and call by reference...code compiles without any error..but prints garbage value?

Tags: c

Hi friends as I am new to C practising hard to understand all nitygrity things in C. While trying Structure I manage to write a piece of code where I am trying to pass structure to a function by value and reference. But I think I am doing something wrong...please help friends...it would be a great help if you guys can guide me to a proper in depth tutorial on Structures...thanks

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>

 struct foo{
        char arr[200];

        int x_val;
        int y_val;

        float result;

        };

 struct foo my_foo;

 int foo_fun(struct foo var);        //proto declearation 

 int foo_fun1(struct foo *var1);    //proto declearation 

 int main()
 {
     //As I was not getting prover string printed by using function foo_fun1
     // I have tried to print directrly calling another ptr here 

     int i = 0;

     struct foo *ptr;

     ptr = (struct foo *)malloc(sizeof(struct foo)*10);

     ptr->arr[0] = "calculator";

     printf("Ptr zero contains a string %s\n",ptr->arr[0]); //even here prints wrong value


     i = foo_fun(my_foo);

     printf("Result from foo_fun is %d\n",i);

    //Expecting this function to print string ....but getting some unexpected result

    foo_fun1(&my_foo);

    system("pause"); 

    return 0;  

 }

 // pass by value 

 int foo_fun(struct foo var)
 {
     int i;
     int total = 0;


for(i=0;i<sizeof(var.arr); i++)

            { var.arr[i] = i;

              total = total+var.arr[i];
             }
     var.x_val = 230;
     var.y_val = 120;

     return total;

     }

 // pass by reference  

 int foo_fun1(struct foo *var1)
 {
     int i = 0;

     var1 = (struct foo *)malloc(sizeof(struct foo)*20);

     var1->arr[0] = "A";

     printf("%s\n",var1->arr);

     return 0;


     }
```

Comment: @NPE Why not, if warnings aren't treated as errors and are just ignored?

Comment: Please put some minimum effort at code formatting when asking a question.

Answer (score 4):

The following is wrong:

```
ptr->arr[0] = "calculator";
```

(BTW, your compiler should have warned you about this.)

You should use `strcpy()` instead.

The same goes for the other place where you're using a similar construct.

Finally, the `malloc()` in `foo_fun1()` is unnecessary. Not only you're overwriting the value of the function argument (why?), you are also leaking memory.

Comment: That's not the only problem, though. There's more: `var1 = (struct foo *)malloc(sizeof(struct foo)*20);` The parameter is trashed and the memory is leaked.

Comment: Thanks a lot NPE...i appreciate your efforts

Answer (score 1):

The line

```
ptr->arr[0] = "calculator";
```

is wrong, you cannot assign a string to a single character, that's what `ptr->arr[0]` represents.

```
ptr->arr = "calculator";
```

would be wrong too, since you cannot assing a string to a char array in that way, you have to use [strcpy()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcpy/).

```
printf("Ptr zero contains a string %s\n",ptr->arr[0]);
```

should also be

```
printf("Ptr zero contains a string %s\n",ptr->arr);
```

since you are printing an array not a single char

Answer (score 1):

Three problems in your code:

You must not cast return value from `malloc()` -

you are trying to assign a constant string to an indexed array - so it should be

`strcpy(ptr->arr, "calculator");` and  `strcpy(var1->arr,"A");`

Also - there is a massive memory leak in your code. No call to `free()` anywhere.